# Set variable to current directory

Tags: php, directory, filesystems

I am trying to set the variable to the current working directory. I used the code below:

```php
$docs_uri = getcwd() . "/head_tag.php";
```

But when I try to put the path in an anchor tag like below:

```php
echo "<a href='$docs_uri'>TEST</a>";
```

Even though it is located there. Because when i remove everything before PROJECT-GMPU like '/applications/MAMP/htdocs/' from the url i get the file.

I get this error:

> The requested URL
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PROJECT-GMPU/data-information-knowledge/javascript-documentation/head_tag.php was not found on this server.

Comment: You can use `__DIR__` for the current directory of the script.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the correct web address?  It looks an awful lot like a file system path.  (It's strange that `htdocs` would be in the address.)

Comment: `getcwd()` returns a filesystem directory path from the filesystem root; URLs have their own root folder which is a subfolder in the filesystem; `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will give you the webserver root from the filesystem root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getcwd() will return you the physical path. It wont return you the web path. the URL  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PROJECT-GMPU/data-information-knowledge/javascript-documentation/head_tag.php

will be rendered to http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PROJECT-GMPU/data-information-knowledge/javascript-documentation/head_tag.php

I believe that aint the path of the application. You can use the following piece of code to determine the path:

```
$currentWebDir = substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```